# How to add a column name for Timeseries when it is indexed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Input: `df.info()`

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Index: 100 entries, 2019-01-16 to 2018-08-23 - I want to add this as my first column to to analysis.
Data columns (total 5 columns):

```
open      100 non-null float64
high      100 non-null float64
low       100 non-null float64
close     100 non-null float64
volume    100 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 9.7+ KB
```

Answer (score 0):

df = df.assign(time=date)
df.head()

Out[76]:
1. open 2. high 3. low  4. close    5. volume   time
2019-01-16  105.2600    106.2550    104.9600    105.3800    29655851    2019-01-16
2019-01-15  102.5100    105.0500    101.8800    105.0100    31587616    2019-01-15
2019-01-14  101.9000    102.8716    101.2600    102.0500    28437079    2019-01-14
2019-01-11  103.1900    103.4400    101.6400    102.8000    28314202    2019-01-11
2019-01-10  103.2200    103.7500    102.3800    103.6000    30067556    2019-01-10